# SQl Compare diffrence of all rows next to each other to the Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Sql column with Time. I want to  output them if the time difference between two columns next to each other is bigger than 1 hour

```
     04:05:44
     06:07:48
     08:15:44
     09:05:22
     11:15:27
     11:35:18
     12:16:54
```

My OutPut should be like this

```
     04:05:44 - 06:07:48
     06:07:48 - 08:15:44
     09:05:22 - 11:15:27
```

It is Possible to write query like this in Sql?
If possible What  should i know  from SQL to perform  that query ?
(I know Basic Level OF SQL and I am learning)

Thanks.

Comment: Post your table structures but if you are subtracting 2 dates use DateDiff() function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates(DateColumn TIME)
INSERT INTO #Dates(DateColumn) VALUES
    ('04:05:44'),
    ('06:07:48'),
    ('08:15:44'),
    ('09:05:22'),
    ('11:15:27'),
    ('11:35:18'),
    ('12:16:54');*/

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) AS RowNumb
    FROM #Dates AS D
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, C.DateColumn, C2.DateColumn) >= 60
```

Comment: Why use order by select 1 when you have to order by date.

Comment: @SalmanA In my example, it did not influence the result. But thanks for pointing that out. I changed the code!

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL 2008, you can use [answer provided by www.Studiosql.nl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204481/634935)

The below code works in MSSQL Server 2012 for displaying results, as you have desired.

You can use [LAG TSQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this.

```
CREATE TABLE #time (timeValue TIME)

INSERT INTO #time 
values
     ('04:05:44'),
     ('06:07:48'),
     ('08:15:44'),
     ('09:05:22'),
     ('11:15:27'),
     ('11:35:18'),
     ('12:16:54');

SELECT temp.*
from
(SELECT timevalue, case when datediff(HH, lag(timevalue,1,timevalue) OVER(order by TIMEVALUE),timevalue) > 1 THEN CONCAT(lag(timevalue,1,timevalue) OVER(order by TIMEVALUE),' - ',timevalue) else null END AS displayvalue 
FROM #time) as temp
where temp.displayValue is not null
```

Comment: Is `lag()` supported for `sql server 2008` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze, Sorry. did not notice that it is SQL 2008. Updated my answer.